# How is the integration time calculated in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am attempting to perform some file processing in AWS where i use an API Gateway to pass a file to a Lambda (5MB or less) for processing. But i am mainly concerned about integration time being only 30 seconds. I am not sure about the internet speed of the clients using my service so a 5MB file might as well take longer than 30 seconds to send to API Gateway. So I am wondering when does the countdown for the timeout begin in API Gateway? Does it start as soon as a connection is made or only when the entire file is uploaded (possibly to some memory in API Gateway) and then passed to lambda (i.e. the countdown only starts when the lambda is invoked.)?

Comment: If your current lambda execution time is close to 30 seconds, then you need to trim it down or use a different solution. If you need to rely on internal aws propagation times for your request, then its clear sign that you will have issues sooner or later with the times.

Comment: @Marcin Lambda is not the issue. The problem is with the time for upload of the file to API gateway

Comment: Why not check it? Just upload your file and check how long it will take for the lambda invokation.

Comment: My internet is fast enough to upload the file such that the timeout is not a problem. I am concerned with users with slow internet connections

Comment: I think in postman you can throttle uploads. But i think integration time starts once your function is invoked. And this will happen when your entire file is uploaded. Lambda funciton is not invoked with partial requests data.

Comment: You might also consider *not* uploading files through API Gateway. It has both a 10MB payload limit and 30s timeout. Consider having the client request a pre-signed S3 URL from your API and then the client can upload the file directly to S3. The client can then invoke an /api/uploaded/id API route in your server, or you could trigger upload post-processing via S3 event to Lambda.